# Passing code as parameter

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to show messages:

```
Common.getHandler().post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Toast.makeText(Common.getContext(), "Text...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Common is a class of mine, and getHandler() will return a handler created in an activity. This way I can call Toast from outside activities. 
This is a good aproach, and it works fine, but I'm wondering if there is another way to make that code a little bit cleaner/shorter.

Something like:

```
Common.run({
    Toast.makeText(Common.getContext(), "Text...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

And the run() method should encapsulate the code passed as argument inside a Runnable.

AFAIK this is called closure and it's possible in Javascript.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about the best you can do in Java. You can only pass objects (and scalars) around, so you either have to create a class implementing Runnable, or do what you are doing now which is to create an anonymous object instance implementing Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not the JavaScript.

Your proposition is not possible, as you cannot pass methods and functions as such easily. the code at the top could be simplified to (with appropriate change to your Common class):

```
Common.run(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I wanted to introduce some custom interface, but didn't in the end. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have "standalone" closures; passing anonymous implementations is the closest facsimile.

The only real way to make it "shorter" is to create a concrete implementation and pass that instead--but that's only shorter at the call site.