# How to replace Display#asyncExec(Runnable) with method?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a lot of code that repeats lines as below. How to make this as method ?

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "_How to make this a method_"? You will always have to wrap your code in a `Runnable` at least, so there isn't really much space that you would save. Just out of curiosity, why do you have to do that so often anyway?

Comment: BTW, very related: [Passing code as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657948/passing-code-as-parameter)

Comment: This piece of code is a standard way in SWT to update GUI from another thread that is not GUI thread. I use that code quite often in my app and i'm searching a way to shorten this, for example make that as method. So question is. But You helped me with that related question. Thank You.

Comment: Any feedback to the two answers?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to make this more prominent, let me post an answer:

The code you have there is as short as it gets, because the only things you can pass to methods are variables or scalars.

---

For the special case where all your calls to `Display#asyncExec(Runnable)` are the same, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    public void myMethod()
    {
        /* Your other code here */
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        /* Update the GUI here */
    }
}
```

---

Another alternative would be to create classes for each GUI update purpose, each implementing `Runnable`:

```
public class GuiUpdaters
{
    public static class TableViewerUpdater implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            /* Update your TableViewer here */
        }
    }

    public static class StatusBarUpdater implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            /* Update your Status bar here */
        }
    }
}
```

You would call them like this:

```
/* Update the TableViewer */
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new TableViewerUpdater());

/* Update the status bar */
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new StatusBarUpdater());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a single instance of your drawing routines, when no arguments are required:

```
final Runnable tableDrawer = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        /* Update your TableViewer here */
    }
};
```

then in the code, just use:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(tableDrawer);
```

A few ways to optimize: If you're already in the displaythread, you can call the run method yourself--otherwise, run it asyncExec.

You can create a helper class to run these types of tasks. The helper class can check for whether you're in or out of the display thread, keep track of the number of times a drawing routine is used, and alert you when a drawing task takes too long to execute. (Anything more than 1000 milliseconds is probably not a good thing, and should be wrapped in a progress dialog.)

If you're doing a lot of GUI updates, group them so you do as many as possible in a single drawing "runnable" event. For instance, if you're drawing lines of text to a console, don't draw a single line for each line of text, instead have an ArrayList of lines that need to be drawn.. then trigger a draw when the list.size()==1. When there is a lot of lines of text to display, the speedup will be dramatic.